# Naming pattern for TypeScript compiled Javascript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, version-control, compilation, ignore

We recently created a Repository for a TypeScript project. We try to `.ignore` all generated files to keep our repository and build processes clean.

Currently our TypeScript files `someFile.ts` are compiled to JavaScript files `someFile.js`. We would like to ignore all compiled files. However, there are javascript files which we would like to track in our repository. This makes it impossible to simply ignore all `src/**/*.js` files.

Is there a way to add a prefix or postfix or other naming adjustment to the compiled javascript files as a compileOption? Something like `file.compiled.js`?

Comment: I think most people opt to set an `outDir` in their tsconfig and ignore the whole build directory. Would that work for you?

Comment: It would work for the repository issue, but I fear that relative paths may break if we would use a seperate directory for compiled files.

Comment: The source directory structure would be replicated in the output directory.

Comment: True, but I meant paths relative to non-ts files (html, css, js, etc) which would not be copied to the output directory. Unless we would copy everything.

Comment: That, or bundling it. Either way, there's an argument to be made about things being simpler when you have a clear separation between your code and your output.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

You could use `--listEmittedFiles` and save the list of compiled files to .gitignore